# How to enforce strict ordering for a Rabbit MQ message listener in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Integration project where I send and receive messages from a RabbitMQ queue.

The order in which the system publishes messages is OK, but the order in which it afterwards receives messages is incorrect.

So I found this paragraph (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-strict-ordering) and configured the listener with: `simpleMessageListenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(1);`.

We had some tests and it functioned well. However, after a week or so it started to give similar ordering issues.

Let me explain a bit more:

I have two flows (`IntegrationFlow`s) in one spring integration application.

In the first `IntegrationFlow` it creates messages and publishes every message into a rabbit queue.

Just before the publishing it logs every message and I can confirm that the `sequenceNumber` increments as expected (in my case 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11).

Then in the second flow is consumes these published messages. Right after each message is received, the flow logs it again. Here I found out that the `sequenceNumber` does not increment as expected (in my case 1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8,9,10,11).

It is very important for this application to handle messages in the right ordering.

When I looked into rabbit's UI I found out the following (most of them are what i expect):

- rabbit has 3 connections (for 3 java applications)
- the connection for my application has 3 channels. 2 of them are idle / have no consumers, 1 has 6 subscribers and a prefetch count of 1.
- every subscriber has a prefetch count of 1
- i am concerned with only 1 of these subscribers (a queue).
- this queue has properties 'ack required' and not 'exclusive'.

I didn't expect 3 channels within my applications connection. I did not configure that myself, maybe Spring Integration / AMQP did that for me.

Now, I think that a another channel might become active and that this causes the ordering problem. But I cannot find this in the logging. And not in the configuration.

Pieces of code:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                         final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2MessageConverter,
                                                                         final MethodInterceptor retryInterceptor) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageConverter(jackson2MessageConverter);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAdviceChain(retryInterceptor);
        // force FIFO ordering (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-strict-ordering):
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(1);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrency();
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow routeIncomingAmqpMessagesFlow(final SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer,
                                                         final Queue q1, final Queue q2, final Queue q3,
                                                         final Queue q4, final Queue q5,
                                                         final Queue q6) {
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6);
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Amqp.inboundAdapter(simpleMessageListenerContainer)
                        .messageConverter(jackson2MessageConverter))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "com.my.thing")
                .headerFilter(MyMessageHeaders.QUEUE_ROUTING_KEY)
                .route(router())
                .get();
    }

    private HeaderValueRouter router() {
        HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE);
        router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.Q1_NAME, Q1_CHANNEL);
        router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.Q2_NAME, Q2_CHANNEL);
        router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.Q3_NAME, Q3_CHANNEL);
        router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.Q4_NAME, Q4_CHANNEL);
        router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.Q5_NAME, Q5_CHANNEL);
        router.setChannelMapping(AmqpConfiguration.Q6_NAME, Q6_CHANNEL);
        router.setResolutionRequired(false);
        router.setDefaultOutputChannelName("errorChannel");
        return router;
    }
```

publish:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow prepareForUpload(final Handler1 handler1) {
        BinaryFileSplitter binaryFileSplitter = new BinaryFileSplitter(true);
        binaryFileSplitter.setChunkSize(chunksize);

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(aFlow)
                .handle(handler1)
                .split(binaryFileSplitter)
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.TRACE, "com.my.log.identifyer")
                // Send message to the correct AMQP queue after successful processing
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(QUEUE_ROUTING_KEY, AmqpConfiguration.Q4_NAME))
                .channel(MyChannels.AMQP_OUTPUT)
                .get();
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outputAmqpFlow(final AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate, final UpdateDb updateDb) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(MyChannels.AMQP_OUTPUT)
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "com.my.log.identify")
                .handle(updateDb)
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)
                        .exchangeName(AmqpConfiguration.THE_TOPIC_EXCHANGE)
                        .routingKeyExpression("headers['queueRoutingKey']"))
                .get();
    }
```

receive:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow handleReceivedMessages() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Q4_CHANNEL)
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, "com.my.log.identifyer")
                .handle(..)
                .aggregate(a -> a.releaseStrategy(new ChunkReleaseStrategy()))
                .transform(..)
                ....(..)..
                ...
```

Comment: Can you show your publishing flow?

Comment: @GaryRussell yes I just added it.

Comment: You may consider to use a `resequence()` before that `aggregate()`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#resequencer

Comment: @ArtemBilan thanks, but does that influence the order of the incoming messages? Or the handle() just before it?

Comment: Well, it depends of the place where you exactly need a proper order. Might be that place for you is a `headerFilter()` just after an `Amqp.inboundAdapter()`. but see Gary's answer. I think he is right: an out of order is a cause or AMQP client async nature. You need to be sure that you use the same AMQP channel.

Comment: I was under the impression that outbound was in the correct order and I expected rabbit to keep it that way. Gary’s answer insinuates that the publishing order was incorrect.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I'm testing this (everything works fine), but I need to trigger this problematic behaviour. Do you have any idea on how to simulate a situation where spring uses different channels?

Comment: With `BoundRabbitChannelAdvice` you can't reproduce an issue any more. You can send into your `Q4_CHANNEL` from different threads and they are going to use different channels.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the documentation you pointed to, you need to add a `BoundRabbitChannelAdvice` to the splitter so that all the downstream flow uses the same channel.

```java
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow flow(RabbitTemplate template) {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                    .split(s -> s.delimiters(",")
                            .advice(new BoundRabbitChannelAdvice(template)))
                    .<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
                    .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(template).routingKey("rk"))
                    .get();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussel. How is the notation for an advice on an AbstractMessageSplitter?

Comment: It's in the documentation (and code snippet above). `e -> e.advice(...)` - second parameter to `split()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'm sorry, but I don't understand it. It is however easy to just add this as a second param. Thanks.

Comment: Don't add the duration parameter unless your connection factory is configured to support simple confirmations.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help